# Automatically create AWS IAM user, content, SQS queues and related permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, configuration, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

I have a cloud setup, with a DynamomDB table with entries - which each have a corresponding SQS queue (created by a lambda when entries are added in the DB)

A number of external systems need access to one or more entries, which means that they should read messages from the SQS queue linked to the entries in the database.

I'm looking for the smartest way to do the following:

1. Create database entries (based on an input JSON string or file reference etc) - this will automatically generate the needed queues
2. Create an IAM user
3. Generate ARNs for all queues generated in (1) and generate a matching set of permissions, so the user created in (2) can read/delete/purge these queues.
4. Output the newly created user credentials and all related items in the database.

Of course I can make a lambda and a javascript that does all of it. But I'm looking for a smarter way to do this, hopefully using the AWS CLI only?

Comment: Have you checked out Cloudformation for this? It can set all that up

Comment: I'm already using CF but I'm not sure how to handle long lists of users, resources (defined in a DB table), queues related to the resources and user permissions for each queue - since it'll be a lot of similar entries in CF. 

Do you have any tips on generating CF resources based on a list instead of defining them all?

Currently, I think I'll just define a list of users for each resource in my database, and then, in the lambda  that creates the queues for the resources, I'll add the ARNs of the users to the permissions for each queue.

Comment: You're going to have to write a script to query the DB and loop through the users at some point, so that script could either create the resources for each user directly, or it could pass the user info as parameters to CF.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing like this:

1. Created user groups in CF
2. Made a shell script for creating users and assigning proper groups
3. Made another shell script for creating resources in the database table, and adding the created user name as a part of the data model
4. Made a lambda (triggered by DB events) that sets permissions on the queues related to the database entries and sets the ARN of the users in the database, as the principal. 
   Works so far!